# Optimizing Process Builder: Early Exit: Worthwhile?

Tags: process-builder, governorlimits

**Given**

- An asynchronous transaction receives Json payload that is transformed by Apex into Assets.
- Process Builder on Asset with a dozen decision blocks, none of which are ever true for the inserted Assets

  [image]

Is it worthwhile (CPU, elapsed time) adding a decision block to the top of the Process Builder to cause an early exit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*this Q&A inspired by running into CPU Limits issues on very large async JSON payloads where 1000+ assets were created from JSON within an [fflib framework](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common) and then evaluated by a complex Process Builder. Could the Process Builder be optimized to improve throughput? (ability to handle more than 1000 Assets per Transaction)*

**CAVEAT: YMMV - every org/app is different**

So, I ran an experiment as shown below (5 trials per use case)

The optimization added a decision block at the top of the Process Builder that stopped evaluation if the Asset was newly-created via the Json-to-Sobject apex.

```
                  Before optimization               After optimization
                           Avg 
# assets per Txn   Elapsed ms CPU ms         Elapsed Savings %   CPU Savings %
     100              5852     3427             7.5%              7.9%
    1000             52751    31842             4.7%              9.5%
```

**Bottomline**

No magic bullet to suddenly reclaiming tons of CPU or elapsed time via early exit from Process Builder. A 7-9% CPU savings is nothing to be sneezed at but don't, like me, get your hopes up that a simple declarative change can make you the star of your org.

*The path to further optimization now leads to looking at the Apex*

Nevertheless, early exit from a Process Builder to avoid needless evaluation of decision blocks that will never be true does save some time on large transactions.